# mysql-connector python, Can't connect to server without database name

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python, mysql-connector

I want to connect to mysql server, not just one database then I want to use the 'USE db ' command to switch between them but python wont accept no database name.

This is my code:

```
global connection
connection = mysql.connector.connect(host='-',user='-',password='-',autocommit=True)
```

Error:
`Error while connecting to MySQL 1046 (3D000): No database selected`